# Rectangle won't be drawn on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have created 2 object. One creates a canvas object and append it to the body of the html and another one should draw a rectangle which isn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
window.onload = function(){


    var oCanvas = {

        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        ctx : document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),

        create : function(){
            oCanvas.canvas.id = "canvas";
            oCanvas.canvas.width = 350;
            oCanvas.canvas.height = 350;
            oCanvas.canvas.style.background = "yellow";
            document.body.appendChild(oCanvas.canvas);

        }
    };
    var oMap = {
        createGrid : function(){
            oCanvas.ctx.fillRect(50, 25, 150, 100);
        }
    };

    oCanvas.create();
    oMap.createGrid();

};
```

Comment: You are creating two different canvases..

Answer (score 2):

To use methods that self-references you can do it this way instead -

- Create an object with an constructor instead - otherwise you won't be able to reference its definitions until after the object has been assigned to a variable causing errors.
- Create a new instance of the object using the `new` keyword.

Now you can further improve it by using for example prototypes, but for simplicity:

```
function myCanvas() {

    /// create a reference to ourselves (saves us some headache later)
    var me = this;

    /// create a canvas as a property on this instance
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    /// now this.canvas exists and we can get the context
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d"),

    /// metod create which references 'me'
    this.create = function(){
        me.canvas.id = "canvas";
        me.canvas.width = 350;
        me.canvas.height = 350;
        me.canvas.style.background = "yellow";
        document.body.appendChild(me.canvas);
    }
};

/// create an instance (you can create several of this)
var oCanvas = new myCanvas();
```

Now it will work as you **[can see in this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/42qrA/2/)**.

Comment: Well, that's what I was trying to achieve with the object notation as you could see, with bad results. I also though about doing it your way but didn't want to confuse the OP with the `new Canvas()` stuff etc. + for your answer. I would pick this one.

Comment: Thanks @matewka. I added some more comments to hopefully make the changes a bit more clear for OP.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating two separate canvases. When defining `ctx` property, you should refer to the `canvas` property, created before. Remove the `ctx` from the object definition and add it below, once the object is already defined:

```
var oCanvas = {

    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    ...
}
oCanvas.ctx = oCanvas.canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Comment: This won't work as `this.canvas` is not defined at this point. http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/42qrA/

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg I also didn't expect it to work but tested it on jsfiddle and it worked for the first time. Strange.

Comment: I get `TypeError: this.canvas is undefined` in console FF, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of undefined ` in Chrome, no errors in yours?

Comment: Now I also have errors but when I run the code for the first time, everything went fine. Maybe jsFiddle cached it somehow. I don't know. I'll fix the answer ASAP.

Comment: The reason is that the assigned object to the var is not defined yet so we cannot self-reference it as it is undefined. We could always add it after the object had been assigned to the var (oCanvas).

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg I'm completely aware of that what you say. I just wanted to test it first in the jsFiddle to make sure it won't work. But somehow it worked (only once). Anyway, I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Seems I was beat, and this is a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20009730/1634430

You are creating 2 elements, and drawing in the wrong one. Solution is here: http://codepen.io/zshift/pen/gxoEA.

instead of

```
...
canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
ctx : document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
...
```

you should write

```
var element = document.createElement("canvas");

...
canvas: element,
ctx: element.getContext("2d"),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a single object you can leave it as a object literal but if you were to create multiple instances then you can use constructor functions and prototype. An introduction to constructor functions and prototype can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).

Assuming there is only one oCanvas instance in use you can change your code to:

```
var oCanvas = {

    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    ctx : null,/can't set it to anything yet
          //oCanvas doesn't exist yet here

    create : function(){
        oCanvas.canvas.id = "canvas";
        oCanvas.canvas.width = 350;
        oCanvas.canvas.height = 350;
        oCanvas.canvas.style.background = "yellow";
        document.body.appendChild(oCanvas.canvas);
        //set the context now
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    }
};
var oMap = {
    createGrid : function(){
        oCanvas.ctx.fillRect(50, 25, 150, 100);
    }
};

oCanvas.create();
oMap.createGrid();
```